# grep and delete two lines above a string

Tags: perl, grep

I have a file that is something like below.

I want to grep for a string say `cde` and find two lines above it and delete in the same file (something like `perl -i`).

```
abc
abc
cde
fgh
lij
lij
klm
mno
pqr
pqr
```

I tried

```
grep -B 2 "cde" a.txt
```

Output

```
abc
abc
cde
```

But now I want to delete the two lines above `cde` so that my final output is

```
cde
fgh
lij
lij
klm
mno
pqr
pqr
```

I have tried

```
grep -v -B  "cde" a.txt
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'push @b, $_; @b = () if /^cde$/; print shift @b if @b == 3; END { print @b }' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work for the small piece of text. However when I apply the same for this part of data                              </data_item>
  </data_item>
</data_item>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> in a different file. It doesnt seem to be recognizing "xml version" string. Command I used perl -ne 'push @b, $_; @b = () if /^xml version$/; print shift @b if @b == 3; END { print @b }' a.txt > b.txt

Comment: That's because you included the boundaries `^` and `$` in the regex.  You'd want `/xml version/`.  Also note, if you're working with XML data, you probably want to use an actual XML parser like `XML::Twig` or `XML::LibXML`.

Comment: Oh wow that's awesome! It works! Is there a way to also define line range for the above line? Say I want to do this only between lines 100 and 1000. Sure will check those parsers.

Comment: Of course, the `$.` variable contains the current line number.  Just note that if your logic gets too complicated, you really should put it in a script for readability.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try and figure out how to add $. to the above command to give the line range. Also what is @b==3 doing? Is it the same as -B 2 in grep command?

Comment: perl -i -ne 'push @b, $_; @b = () if /xml version/; print shift @b if @b == 3 && if $.>=2 && $.<=3000; END { print @b }' a.txt Gives an error with && that I added. Actually instead of 3000 I want to write from line 2 until end of file

Comment: The 'if @b == 3` is limiting the buffer to just the two previous lines.  To do this filtering only within a certain range, flush the buffer outside of that range.  `push @b, $_; if ($. < 100 || $. > 1000) {print @b; @b = ();}`

Comment: @user3614491: Your requirement has modified so much from your question that it would be best if you posted a nw question rather than adding endlessly to a trail of comments. A comment is supposed to be a comment on the post, not a further question

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution.

```
awk 'FNR==NR {if (/cde/) f=NR;next} FNR!=f-1 && FNR!=f-2' file{,} > tmp && mv tmp file
cde
fgh
lij
lij
klm
mno
pqr
pqr
```

`file{,}` is the same as `file file`. Make `awk` read the file two times.
First time look for `cde` and store it in a variable `f`
Second time print if record is not -1 or -2 compare to the finding
`> tmp && mv tmp file` store output in a `tmp` file, then write back to original file, like `-i`